# iPhone-like unified inbox/messaging client for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, email, iphone

Is there a unified messaging client for Windows 7 that behaves like email on the iPhone?

I need it to play nicely with Exchange and free Yahoo! mail. Optimally, it should handle multiple exchange accounts. Bonus points if it can import calendars, too.

Comment: I don't think one exists.  Yahoo mail can't be downloaded to a computer for free (I think, if I'm wrong, please tell me!)

Comment: @wizlog I don't have a yahoo mail account, but a quick google turned up a blog post detailing a hack to [enable free POP access to Yahoo! Mail](http://bit.ly/rWS3oP); most recent comments at the bottom of the page indicate the trick still works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Inbox2](http://www.inbox2.com/) seems to fit your needs well.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! I can't believe I hadn't heard of inbox2. It has been around for a while now. It it glitchy -- still can't read my exchange email, but it has social networking hooks FTW. Thanks for the suggestion.